# How to get clients Time zone in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timezone

who can write a function to get clients Time zone,return value like:`EDT` `EST` `IST` and so on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939685/get-client-time-zone-from-browser May be a duplicate?

Comment: You really don't want abbreviations like that. If you get CST, is it China Standard Time (UTC + 8), or Cuba Standard Time (UTC - 5)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`toTimeString()` method give time with the timezone name try out below...

```
var d=new Date();
var n=d.toTimeString();     

ouput

03:41:07 GMT+0800 (PHT) or 09:43:01 EDT
```

## Demo

**or**

Check [: Automatic Timezone Detection Using JavaScript](http://www.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript)

download jstz.min.js and add a function to your html page

```
    <script language="javascript">
        function getTimezoneName() {
            timezone = jstz.determine_timezone()
            return timezone.name();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Date().getTimezoneOffset() function and then build a hash table from this URL [timeanddate](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/) to relate it to if you want to use the time zone value.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the result of calling the `toString` method of a Date object, you'll get a value that's something like "Tue Apr 24 2012 23:30:54 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)". This will depend on what your system locale is set to.

From there you can match each capital letter within the parentheses.

```
var paren = new Date().toString().match(/\(.+\)/);
return paren ? paren[0].match(/([A-Z])/g).join("") : "";
```

The catch is that not every browser will include the parenthesised values.

If you're targeting Firefox with a known Java plugin, you can also exploit the `java` object in Javascript to create a new TimeZone (java.util.TimeZone) object based on a name (eg. "America/Los_Angeles"), then call the `getDisplayName` method to give you the name.

Comment: Unfortunately I get "Thu Sep 11 2014 11:29:07 GMT+1000 (EST)" when I use new Date().toString(); in Australia in Chrome. This is confusing due to the US EST time zone GMT-0400.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jstz](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) to get the timezone name:

```
jstz.determine().name();
```

It returns timezone names (like `'America/New York'`) which you can then use with `moment.js` etc.

An offset (eg from a js `Date` object) is not enough, because it does not carry the additional DST information (you won't know whether the time needs to be adjusted for Daylight Savings and when).

Answer (score 0):

- get client time zone in javascript
- output from -12 : +12
- you can modify the output by change on this line `-Math.round(a/60)+':'+-(a%60);` Like `-Math.round(a/60);` you get //+2

  ```
  var a = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
  var res = -Math.round(a/60)+':'+-(a%60);
  res = res < 0 ?res : '+'+res;
  console.log(res);
  ```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind getting the full name, try this:

let timeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;  // like "America/Chicago"

(Oh, you asked 11 years ago. My bad. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

This is the perfect answer to get full timezone of country-

```
var a = new Date($.now());     
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;`enter code here`
var matches = regExp.exec(a);
alert(matches[1]);
```

this alert will give you output like indian standard time,american standard time,african standard time:

```
//$("#timezone option:contains(" + matches[1] + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: I'm sorry but link in your answer looks like a spam