# Serialize NodaTime JSON

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

I am making a prototype project of NodaTime compared to BCL's DateTime, but executing this result gives me recursionLimit exceeded error.

[image: Recursion limit exceeded]

This is the function I am using to JSONify my viewmodel. The error happens after this function returns.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetDates(int numOfDatesToRetrieve)
    {
        List<DateTimeModel> dateTimeModelList = BuildDateTimeModelList(numOfDatesToRetrieve);

        JsonResult result = Json(dateTimeModelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return result;
    }
```

My view model is built properly when I inspected it. 
Here is the code for my view model.

```
public class DateTimeModel
{
    public int ID;

    public LocalDateTime NodaLocalDateTimeUTC;
    public LocalDateTime NodaLocalDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetZoneOrNull(BCLTimezoneID);

            //ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = NodaLocalDateTimeUTC.InUtc().WithZone(dateTimeZone);

            OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = new OffsetDateTime(NodaLocalDateTimeUTC, Offset.Zero);
            ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = new ZonedDateTime(offsetDateTime.ToInstant(), dateTimeZone);
            return zonedDateTime.LocalDateTime;
        }
    }

    public OffsetDateTime NodaOffsetDateTime;

    public DateTime BclDateTimeUTC;
    public DateTime BclLocalDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(BclDateTimeUTC, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            TimeZoneInfo nzTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(BCLTimezoneID);
            DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, nzTimeZone);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public DateTimeOffset BclDateTimeOffset;
    //public int Offset;
    public string OriginalDateString;
    public string BCLTimezoneID;
}
```

I am sure that the NodaTime objects are not serializing correctly because when I comment the code from the viewModel the JsonResult is able to execute.

I read this off this page [NodaTime API Reference](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/html/N_NodaTime_Serialization_JsonNet.htm)

> Code in this namespace is not currently included in Noda Time NuGet packages; it is still deemed "experimental". To use these serializers, please download and build the Noda Time source code from the project home page.

So I downloaded and built the source code and replaced the dll's my project references but I don't know how to implement the JsonSerialization classes.

Can someone explain to me how to use NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet classes to make my NodaTime objects serializable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We don't currently have any support for `JavaScriptSerializer`: I suspect you'll have to use [Json.NET](http://json.net) for *all* your JSON serialization. The [user guide page on serialization](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/serialization.html) gives a *little* bit more information, but it does mostly assume you already know about Json.NET.

The good news is that Json.NET is pretty easy to use - you may well find it's as simple as:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ConfigureForNodaTime();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, settings);
```

(Or use `JsonSerializer`.)

As an aside, the way you're using the Noda Time types is a little odd to say the least - it may well be worth asking another question with details of what you're trying to achieve, and we can work out a more idiomatic way of doing it :)

Comment: I was just making an example project that persists datetime from client -> server -> database and back again. So I can compare the BCL library to NodaTime? What is odd about my technique? If it is because I use properties, I just wanted them to be serializable.

Comment: @mac10688: It's the way you're dealing with the various types - you're going through a lot of hoops for conversions, but it's not clear to me what those conversions are meant to be achieving. The very fact that you've got a field called of `NodaLocalDateTimeUTC` is worrying - because a `LocalDateTime` isn't conceptually in any time zone. I'm keen to help you understand the concepts and types involved - partly because it may lead us to write better documentation :)

Comment: I see what you are saying. Is it that LocalDateTime doesn't have a 'Kind' property for a reason, and you think I shouldn't force it? I did this because I wanted to store the datetime in UTC and a timezoneID and with that information I would be able to construct the localized time when I pass it back to the client. In the same example I am also storing datetimeoffset. So maybe the best solution is to store datetimeoffset with the timezoneID. In my prototype project I ultimately want to see how nodatime and bcl differ in side by side comparisons (i.e. persisting DateTimes and manipulating them).

Comment: @mac10688: Yes. You should read up on all the different concepts in Noda Time - http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.0.x/docs/userguide/concepts.html and http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.0.x/docs/userguide/type-choices.html. It sounds like you should actually just be storing a `ZonedDateTime`, which can be stored as an `Instant` (using the `Ticks` property to get a `long` value) and a time zone ID. Of course you could convert to a `DateTimeOffset` (and time zone ID) if that's easier to store in the database.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet: can u tell me what is the advantage of using Nodatime library instead of DotNet built-in datetime ?

Comment: @Thomas: See http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

Comment: @JonSkeet:i have one more question about noda library. i am in situation where i need to fetch timezone id from browser and need to pass that timezone id to server side code and server side code will return current time based on timezone id. the problem is browser return timezone id like this way "India Standard Time or GMT Standard Time" and noda is not accepting this timezone id and i came to know noda will accept if we give timezone id like this way "Asia/Kolkata" or "Etc/GMT".how noda can parse browser returned timezone id and return current time based on that timezone id.

Comment: @Thomas: If you have another question, you should ask it *as* a separate question - but there are lots of questions about obtaining time zone IDs from Javascript already. Search on Stack Overflow for those questions. (It's not at all clear where you're getting "India Standard Time" from anyway... "browser return timezone id" doesn't give much detail.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sorry to disturb you. i have posted a thread on the same already but looking for good answer. here is the url of my thread...if possible please see it and give your suggestion. here is the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626798/nodatime-time-zone-related-issue-using-nodatime-library-c-sharp/26626997?noredirect=1#comment41904193_26626997

Comment: @Thomas: You still haven't explained there where you got the name from (or rather, *how* you got it from the browser). As I said, there are lots of *existing* Stack Overflow questions for getting tzdb IDs from Javascript.

Comment: @JonSkeet: sorry jon. i just edit my question a bit and please see my edit portion and then you can see i am achieving timezone id by js which is working with Noda after feeding timezone id to it. looking for your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @Thomas: It sounds like you still haven't looked for *other* questions which give the answer you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939685/get-client-time-zone-from-browser for example

Comment: @JonSkeet If you're curious where "Asia/Kolkata" comes from http://stackoverflow.com/a/26626997/397817 . It wasn't from the browser!

Comment: @StephenKennedy: Yup, it's where the OP got "Indian Standard Time" from which was confusing me, until he posted the code (now edited out)...

Answer (score 3):

Serialization is [supported for JSON.NET in Noda Time 2.0+](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/userguide/serialization).

You'll need to install the package with NuGet:

```
> Install-Package NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet
```

And then configure your serializer settings to use it. This **won't work with the default serializer/deserializer** - you need to configure one explicitly.

We chose to use one statically. Your usage may be different. Here is an example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet; // << Needed for the extension method to appear!
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings _JsonSettings;

        static MyClass()
        {
            _JsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                // To be honest, I am not sure these are needed for NodaTime,
                // but they are useful for `DateTime` objects in other cases.
                // Be careful copy/pasting these.
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
            };

            // Enable NodaTime serialization
            // See: https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/userguide/serialization
            _JsonSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
        }

        // The rest of your code...
    }
}
```