# Time Zone support in Requests.get results

Tags: python, timezone

I am scraping a simple web page using Python. When I look at the web page using Chrome I get:

8/13 2:20 PM - this is the correct time for my time zone

In on one of the date strings (returns as a string)

I am using requests.get (Same results with urllib2) with the call:

```
thepage = requests.get('http://fakepage.com')
```

and when I get everything decoded I get:
  8/13 4:20 PM - since it's off by two hours exactly, I assume it's the server side detecting my time zone.

is there any way to send my time zone in the requests.get call? or perhaps I am looking at it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

No, your browser doesn't send any time information when making a request. The server would not be able to adjust the timezone in the HTML sent.

The common way to do what you observed is using JavaScript; see [get client time zone from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939685/get-client-time-zone-from-browser) for example. Your browser executed code that translated the datetime in the page to your local timezone, not the server.

This is far more efficient as well; the server just has to send **one** version of the HTML page to every client; this is far more cachable.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm a noob here so please be patient. This leads me back to a local environment setting. It's an ASP.NET site so the code is actually running on the server building the HTML for the client to render. (right?) The shared server where I run the python script has the correct time. Is there any way to set it up so the ASP.NET site has the right time zone?

Comment: @AndyH - That's entirely up to that particular ASP.net code, which you didn't show us in your question.

Comment: @AndyH: sure you can, but why not do this after parsing the date on the client instead?

Comment: The data is coming to me as plain text. it's a very simple page returned. I can convert the text to time then adjust for the timezone. I may not be asking the right question. How come when I get a page with Chrome does it have the right time (for my time zone) but when I use Request.get it has a differnt time zone.

Comment: @AndyH: then *parse the datetime and convert it*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - My edit crossed your response. I can do that, it just doesn't seem like I should have to. Why is the time displayed by Chrome different than what is returned by request.get?

Comment: @AndyH: I already stated that; Chrome is probably instructed to run JavaScript code to do the conversion.

Answer (score -2):

SOLVED - I had a one character typo in the request which returned everything exactly the same HTML payload between Chrome and request.get EXCEPT for the time.

Thanks everyone for your time.