# How to convert a timestamp string to local time using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, timestamp

I have a JSP page in which I am pulling timestamp stored in database as string which has the form   `Thu Aug 21 2014 22:09:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

Of Course, I am able to display it as it is in the page, however I was looking for a solution in javascript that would enable me convert this timestamp as per user's local timezone.

Is there a way to do this ? Or for such a timestamp it's not possible ? Any help is greatly appreciated, well my question may sound silly as I am still familiarizing myself with javascript.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939685/get-client-time-zone-from-browser

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I think that's not what I am looking for, I don't want to detect user's timezone, rather I was looking for a way to convert my timestamp to a javascript date object which can be rendered as per the local timezone.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I figured it out myself and I am able to accomplish what I needed. Passing the `timestamp` from database to var `new Date(timestamp)` get it converted to local time, it takes care of timezone and offsets as well.
Thanks for your time experts! :)

Answer (score 5):

You may try this

```
var timezone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

> The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and
>   local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the
>   local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead. For example,
>   if your time zone is UTC+10 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), -600
>   will be returned. Daylight savings time prevents this value from being
>   a constant even for a given locale

Also here is an interesting article which may help you:- **[Auto detect a time zone with JavaScript](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/)**

EDIT:

```
var d = new Date(myYear, myMonth, myDate);
d.setTime( d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I think that's not what I am looking for, I don't want to detect user's timezone, rather I was looking for a way to convert my timestamp to a javascript date object which can be rendered as per the local timezone.

Comment: @RaghvendraMishra:- Updated my ansswer. Hope thats what you are looking for! :)

Comment: Thanks Again @RT :- but I don't have year, month and date separately, all I have is a timestamp of the format `Thu Aug 21 2014 22:09:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).` and was looking to directly convert this to a particular user's timezone settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use AngularJS, it will be much more easier and straightforward to convert from 1408648665 to Thu, 21 Aug 2014 19:17:45 GMT

```
    //html
    <div ng-controller="TimeCtrl">
      Date: {{timeStamp + '000' | date: 'medium'}}
    </div>

    //js
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('TimeCtrl', function time($scope) {
      $scope.timeStamp = 1408648665;
      console.log("hello");
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hq0ry1vm/2/

Comment: Thanks @admix. Not really what I require here. :)