# Timestamp change issue in web application

Tags: java, timestamp, jackson

In my spring based web application, I am  using spring and jackson jar for converting json-object conversion.
Here I am facing a problem , one of my bean has a field `java.util.Timestamp` `registerDate`.

From the form (using angular js )I am setting value as `2016-01-22 22:30:00`. 
But in my controller the field value changed to different one that is `2016-01-22 12:30:00`.

Comment: Check your timezones

Comment: @Adam Martin ,Please suggest me a good solution for this

Comment: @AdamMartin is probably right. Just check your time zone . Print it and you will see that they are different with your browser time.

Comment: Yes. Thank you guys for valuable suggestion,here my browser time is in IST and my server is hosted @ digital ocean(cloud),EST. But still I don't have a clear solution for fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem here is your timezone, what you can do is send the browser timezone ([get client time zone from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939685/get-client-time-zone-from-browser)) along with your form data and in your server you can calculate the appropriate time in your controller.
Another option is that you can simply pass the date as a String and then convert it when needed.

Comment: Thank you. I will opt for the second option