# Telegram Bot. Get User timezone

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

When developing bot for Telegram is there any way to get user timezone? Date field in Message object contains UNIX timestamp only. I want to create bot sending some messages an fixed time of day to subscribed user. User can have different time zones and I don't want to force users to explicit send their timezone to bot in message.

Comment: No! There is no such ability currently in Telegram Bot API

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's imposible by standard Bot API.

You can ask user for location, and next, from this location calculate timezone for user.

Answer (score 4):

I've added `/set_utc_offset` command to my bot where users enter the time difference in minutes compared to UTC

Answer (score 1):

You can also create link button which opens temprorary browser window.

Where you request timezone from browser
encodeURIComponent(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
[browser's timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939685/get-client-time-zone-from-browser)
and redirect back with timezone in query string and store it.

And than this window can be automatically closed by redirecting to your bot
[https://t.me/{your_bot_name}](https://t.me/%7Byour_bot_name%7D)