# Create date object that is same for everyone from same timestamp

Tags: javascript

On my site I am getting the current time via ajax function that returns the servers current timestamp and then creating a date object.

```
$.post(flipCountdownObj.ajax_url, data, function(response) {

        var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(response) * 1000);
        alert("Server says the time is " + currentTime.toLocaleTimeString());

        // code to create my countdown here...

}
```

My logic then goes on to compare that date to various other dates to provide countdowns and event status.

My problem is though that everyone is getting different times.

I am in GMT.  The server is in EST.  For me it says the correct time but people in EST are saying that it is 4 hours out.

I don't understand why this is happening as the timestamp should be the same for everyone.

I saw a post saying about setting UTC time but not sure exactly what I am meant to do.  Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i've found a way a while ago where i use JS Date to figure out the browser timezone and add this difference in a cookie so i could calculate the UTC in PHP. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939685/get-client-time-zone-from-browser. But you can do this with JS only.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
    var serverOffset = -300*60000; // -5 hrs is 300 minutes

    var usersDate = new Date();
    var userOffset = usersDate.getTimezoneOffset()* 60000;

    var currentTime = new Date((parseInt(response) * 1000) + userOffset + serverOffset);
```