# how to send browser time to mysql sever for save php

Tags: php

how to send browser time to MySQL server for save through php.
I search lot's of time on the internet, but I did not find a good answer.
suppose my browser time is  17-Sep-2018 3:10:55

So how can I store this in my database. I Use NOW(), DATE but nothing the write answer.thanx in advanced.

Comment: Why do you care about the browser's time? Is this for timezone support or something?

Comment: Javascript... PHP runs on the server, after being executed and compiled the user only sees the rendered page. Javascript in the other hand is executed on the local user's browser.

Comment: yes, you can say ceejayoz

Comment: Could you echo html that uses js to get the time and then send that via xmlhttp request?

Kinda hacky, but does the client-side journey for you?

I think that's what Samuel might have been saying, to be fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use Javascript; PHP is executed on the server - which is not the same as the user's browser or location.

For example:

```
(function() {
  var url = '/some/file.php?date=' + new Date();

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors'
  })
  .then(response() => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Could not complete request:', error));
})();
```

Then in the Server you can process the request:

```
<?php

// request date contains the date from our JS request

if( $_REQUEST['date'] )
{
  // format it how you want it
  $date = date('j M Y h:i:s a', $_REQUEST['date']);

  // check and make sure variable exists
  if( $date )
  {
    // connect to mysql (this is not recomended... better to use some sort of library)
    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'site');

    // safely store it with prepared statements
    $stmt = $mysql->prepare('INSERT INTO visits (visist_time) VALUES (?)');
    if($stmt = $stmt->bind_param('d', $date))
    {
      // this will execute the query
      $stmt->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

This is not a perfect answer; I am not sure why you want to get a timestamp for users who visit, but that will in theory be able to record timestamps every time the JS script is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the browser time - it could easily be incorrect, and will wreak havoc on users who travel between timezones as well. (If I go visit Australia, all my appointments in your database would suddenly be 14 hours off...)

Instead, you should store the *server's* time - which should always be correct using something like NTP - and in UTC. When you need to show a date to the user, you can use JavaScript to [convert the timestamp into the correct time based on the browser's current GMT offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939685/get-client-time-zone-from-browser).

Another option is having the user provide their chosen timezone as a setting, and converting to that.