# Format highcharts date tooltip to display timezone

Tags: highcharts

I want to display the time zone on the date/time tooltip.

The `xDateFormat` option does not have an option to display timezone.

https://jsfiddle.net/u7z28fbp/1/

For eg:

Currently the date tooltip shows: `Friday, April 5, 2019`

I want it to show: `Friday, April 5, 2019 UTC +00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/q8s2jdgp/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},

tooltip: {
    xDateFormat: '%A, %B %d, %Y UTC ' + dayjs().format("Z") ,
    shared: true
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}, {
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4].reverse()
}]
});
```

If you want to change what the UTC value is to the right you will want to write some code around that to create a variable and use concatenation or interpolation.

I used day.js, here are other ways you can get the timestamp from the browser. [get client time zone from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939685/get-client-time-zone-from-browser)

There are a few resources around to do datetime formatting, I used this one: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-find-a-time-format-for-rubys-strftime

Comment: This is awesome, thanks heaps! Sidenote, the `%A` formatter to display the full day is not documented in Highcharts. But thanks to you I found out about that too! Cheers dude

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional date format specifier to `Highcharts.dateFormats` object:

```
Highcharts.dateFormats = {
    'Z': function(time) {
        return new Date(time).getTimezoneOffset() / 60
    }
}


Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    ...,
    tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%A, %B %d, %Y UTC %Z'
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kt7bucjv/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.html#.dateFormats