# What is this little note below DateField that is displayed in Django Admin?

Tags: django

Hi I have defined a CD Model in my models.py file in my app and linked it to the admin page. However, I noticed this little note below the Date field. 'You are 8 hours ahead of server time'. What does it mean?

[image]

I tried finding information about it but still couldn't get a good understanding of it.

Comment: That the timezone in your browser is a different one than the one at the server side.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem, how django knows the browser timezone?

Comment: Through JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6939685/67579 or with a request header.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was digging into [admin source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b2601a77f97eb84d7574e6ac68a38a636bdc0e1e/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js#L33-L34) at this time. Thanks.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem, is it a good thing to align the two timezones? What's your take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django save the server offset in [body tag data attribute](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b2601a77f97eb84d7574e6ac68a38a636bdc0e1e/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html#L26-L27) ie in `<body data-admin-utc-offset="{% now "Z" %}">`.
And will do the below calculation in [js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b2601a77f97eb84d7574e6ac68a38a636bdc0e1e/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js#L33-L34) to show the local time:

```js
function createwarning() {
  let timezoneOffset = 0;
  const serverOffset = document.body.dataset.adminUtcOffset;
  console.log(serverOffset)
  if (serverOffset) {
    const localOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * -60;
    timezoneOffset = localOffset - serverOffset
    console.log(timezoneOffset / 3600)
  }
}
createwarning()
```

```html
<body data-admin-utc-offset="0"></body>
```