# How to create cronjob such that reminders are triggered as per user timezone?

Tags: python, cron, utc, reminders

I have an app where I need to send reminders for upcoming sessions. Now, users are spread across the globe. There session timing is stored in UTC in the database. Now, I am getting confused as to how should I design the cronjob such that notifications are sent at 4pm as per user local timezone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would run the cronjob every hour and then every hour select the users with the right timezone. depending on how you have stored their prefered timezone or location.

Comment: if your users interact with your app via web you can get their local timezone via javascript and then store it in the server  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939685/get-client-time-zone-from-browser